# maven-surefire-plugin doesn't run parallel tests

Tags: maven, parallel-processing, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a project Serenity+Java+JUnit and I try to run my tests in parallel.
I paste this into my pom and after `mvn integration-test`, it is still run in a chain :(
What I have done wrong?

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>all</parallel>
                <forkMode>perthread</forkMode>
                <threadCount>4</threadCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have resolved it by adding another plugin instead of surefire-plugin

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>5</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <databaseSchema>MY_TEST_SCHEMA_5</databaseSchema>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <workingDirectory>FORK_DIRECTORY_5</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I also note a different version of the plugin with different arguments. That might have some effect as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if what your answer suggests is correct. You have placed concurrency configuration in Maven Failsafe, a plugin which is responsible for safely terminating the test execution once an exception has occurred therein. Although, as you claim it this has resolved your issue, it might impact your project in the long run.

According to [Maven's website](http://maven.apache.org/surefire-archives/surefire-2.17/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html), the below code should be placed under Maven Surefire configuration.

```
<forkCount>5</forkCount>
<reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
<argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
```

Having followed these guidelines, I was able to successfully run tests in parallel with only updating Surefire plugin.